# How to write unit test for async function that not return any value in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, async-await

I have issue about unit test of Async function, Currently I using `MockingBird` for checking function in `Worker class` was called from `Interactor class` or not. The issue is sometime this unit test is pass. Sometime it's not.

I've no idea about it :( . And it doesn't have any error from XCode's console. just `time out` and fail....

`interactor` and `worker` like below.

```
// Interactor.swift
func markBookAsOpen() {
    Task {
        await self.worker.logOpened(id: self.bookId)
    }
}
```

```
// Worker.swift
func logOpened(id: String) async {
    await self.service.logOpened(id: id)
}
```

And this one is my unit test function.

```
func test_markBookAsOpen_shouldCallAtWorker() async {
    // Given
    self.interactor.markBookAsOpen()
    
    // When
    verify(await self.workerMock.logOpened(id: any(String.self))).wasCalled(1)
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I would question whether it makes sense to unit test some functionality that the app does not offer. You have a method that creates an asynchronous task and does not see if the task has started, much less `await` its result. So, it does not make too much sense to unit test behavior that does not exist. In unit tests, we test exposed interfaces, not hidden side-effects.

That being said, when writing asynchronous code, I personally always provide the ability to know when this asynchronous task is finished. Not only does this serve testability, but it is generally just a good idea, regardless.

So, you have a couple of alternatives:

1. You could just make `markBookAsOpen` an `async` method:

   ```swift
   func markBookAsOpen() async {
       await worker.logOpened(id: bookId)
   }
   ```

   You can then just unit test this `async` rendition.

   ```swift
   func testMarkBookAsOpen() async {
       await interactor.markBookAsOpen()

       …
   }
   ```
2. You could make `markBookAsOpen` to return the created task (so that the caller can decide whether it wants to await the result, whether it might want to save that so it can cancel it later, etc.):

   ```swift
   @discardableResult
   func markBookAsOpen() -> Task<Void, Never> {
       Task {
           await worker.logOpened(id: bookId)
       }
   }
   ```

   Then you can test it like so:

   ```swift
   func testMarkBookAsOpen() async {
       let task = interactor.markBookAsOpen()
       _ = await task.result

       …
   }
   ```

   By making this a `@discardableResult`, you do not require the caller to do anything with the resulting task, but it affords you that capability.

Personally, I would lean towards option 1 (as I think it is inadvisable to introduce [unstructured concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency#Unstructured-Concurrency) inside the interactor), but either works. And, for the sake of completeness, there are other patterns, as well (e.g., optional completion handler closures and expectations, etc.). But the idea is the same, namely to offer the capability to know when an asynchronous task is done. Then testing this becomes trivial.